# Delete from a table with JOIN, GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql

I have a table `carts` and `cartitems`, the second one has a foreign key to the first. Now I want to delete all rows from `carts` that are older than 3 months and have no related `cartitems`. The following query gives me the correct result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `carts` c
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `cartitems` i ON (  `c`.`id` =  `i`.`cart_id` ) 
WHERE  `c`.`last_updated` < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
GROUP BY  `c`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(  `i`.`id` ) = 0;
```

But I can't figure out how to turn this query into a `DELETE`.

Also, since there are ~10 million rows in the `carts` table, I'd be thankful for suggestions on how to improve this query :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following without `LIMIT` or with a `LIMIT` to delete the rows in batches.

```
DELETE c
FROM  carts c
WHERE c.last_updated < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM cartitems i 
        WHERE c.id = i.cart_id
     ) 
LIMIT 10000 ;                           --- optional
```

Answer (score 0):

That exists query should work:

```
DELETE FROM `carts` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM  `carts` c
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `cartitems` i ON (  `c`.`id` =  `i`.`cart_id` ) 
WHERE  `c`.`last_updated` < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
GROUP BY  `c`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(  `i`.`id` ) = 0);
```

This query should delete all rows that are in the result set.

Please note that you can exchange the asterisk with null or any other value.

A second try:

```
DELETE FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` IN (SELECT `c`.`id` 
FROM  `carts` c
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `cartitems` i ON (  `c`.`id` =  `i`.`cart_id` ) 
WHERE  `c`.`last_updated` < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
GROUP BY  `c`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(  `i`.`id` ) = 0);
```

That one generates a list of ids (I hope that c.id is your primary key) and delete all rows related to that ids.

Comment: I get this error message:
"#1093 - You can't specify target table 'carts' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: @BenjaminWohlwend is `carts` a view? Or do you have any triggers on any related tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
DELETE FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM  `carts` c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `cartitems` i ON (  `c`.`id` =  `i`.`cart_id` ) 
    WHERE  `c`.`last_updated` < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
    GROUP BY  `c`.`id` 
    HAVING COUNT(  `i`.`id` ) = 0
);
```

I am not sure about it though :)